# Javascript "getElementById" return null in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, javascript-controller, javascript-debugging, onclickjavascript

Anyone help me, why Javascript "getElementById" return null in Visualforce Page.

In my form, I have "Radio button" and "inputtextarea"
My requirement is whenever click the radio button in visualforce,based on the condition "inputtextarea" need to hide.Below is my code.

Javascript code:

---

```
<script>
    function myFunction(v) 
    {
      var inputcpf = document.getElementById('iptext2');

        // console.log('Id of the Inputtext :' + inputcpf);
        alert(inputcpf);
        if(v.value =="Excellent")
            //document.getElementById("iptext2").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById('iptext2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        else
            //document.getElementById("iptext2").style.display="none"; 
            document.getElementById('iptext2').style.visibility = 'visible';
            return;            
    }    
    
</script>
```

Visualforce page Code:

---

```
<Table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" columns="0" class="big"> 
   <tr >
      <td colspan="5" class="fieldLabel">                     
          <p style="font-size: 20px;">
                 <b> How satisified you are with our Service? </b>
          </p>     

          <apex:selectRadio value="{!SelectedAnswer}"  
                            onclick="myFunction(this)"
                            style="font-size: 20px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;" >
                            <apex:SelectOptions value="{!Items}" id="SelOP1"/>                                  
          </apex:selectRadio>
      </td>
    </tr> 
</Table>  
<Table>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <p style="font-size: 15px;">
               <b>How could we improve?</b>
          </p>                               
          <apex:inputTextarea id="iptext2"  value="{!EnteredText}"  style="width: 350px;"/>
        </td>
     </tr>
</Table>
```

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm).

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce elements (those that start with `<apex:`) have their id generated from the provided id. You should generally use the `$Component` variable to access these elements:

```
document.getElementById("{!$Component.iptext2}")
```

`$Component` won't work for components that generate elements in a loop. You'd be better off using something like:

```
<apex:selectOptions html-data-id="selectOption" ...
```

So you can then query:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="selectOption"]')
```

Comment: Sorry.. Don't understand. Able to provide sample code. It's a great help for me